# Check if value in column exists in another file and print row from the other file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using Python, how can I check if a value in a column exists in another file using Python csv?

For example I have two files:

File1:

```
"time",text,"number","name"
"15:08:31.758","lorem dolor ipsum",6475,"Account1"
"15:08:31.748","lorem ipsum

dolor ",5145,"Account2"
"15:56:41.634","dolor ipsum lorem",4162,"Account3"
```

File2:

```
"time",text,"number"
"15:48:34.865",YES,5145
"15:46:08.347",Yes,5142
"15:39:04.391",Yes,5146
"15:37:48.270",YES,4389
"15:36:37.476",Yes,5149
"15:30:23.950",YES,4166
"15:17:27.071",Yes,4388
"15:17:02.016",Yes,5144
"15:09:01.167",yes,2045
```

And I want to search from File1 each value in the number column (6475, 5145, and 4162) and if the value exists in the number field in File2 then print the entire row in File2. My output would look as such:

```
"15:48:34.865",YES,5145
```

Comment: You could use the csv python module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `csv` module you could read and parse CSV file easily, and compare the value in the number column of each file to find matches

here for example, we read and open a `File1.csv` file then a `File2.csv` file with a `DictReader`, then we check if the number value in each row is in the set of value we extracted from `File1.csv`

```
import csv

with open('File1.csv', newline='') as f1:
    reader1 = csv.DictReader(f1)
    numbers1 = set(row['number'] for row in reader1)

with open('File2.csv', newline='') as f2:
    reader2 = csv.DictReader(f2)
    for row in reader2:
        if row['number'] in numbers1:
            print(row)
```

Comment: This is great thank you so much I was able to extract the info from File2. Is it possible to print individual columns from File1 as well as the row from File2 in the same line?

Comment: Yes, You can access the values for a specific column in a row using the column header as the key